# Change path "d" attribute to curve the line

Tags: javascript, svg

I am trying to change "d" attribute of all lines in certain SVG map to make straigh lines curved.

`d="M514 222L488 66"`

Is there any universal algorithm to change any straigt line "d" attribute (like this one above) and get curved line as result?

Comment: use an elliptical arc or bezier curve command instead per https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html

Comment: I have tried that before, but I can not get it right. I have a map library that generates those paths and then i have js script that select those lines and changes d attribute.

Comment: Either shiow us what you tried and explain why it's "not right" or use an SVG editor such as Inkscape to draw whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it: For the curve (a quadratic Bézier curve Q) I need to calculate the position of the control point. In this case I want the control point in the middle of the line at a distance R.

Please read the comments in the code to understand it.

```js
// a variable to define the curvature 
let R = 50;
// the points of the original line
let linePoints = [
  {x:514,y:222},
  {x:488,y:66}
]
//the length of the line
let length = thePath.getTotalLength();
//a point in the middle of the line
let point = thePath.getPointAtLength(length/2);
// calculate the angle of the line
let dy = linePoints[1].y - linePoints[0].y;
let dx = linePoints[1].x - linePoints[0].x;
let angle = Math.atan2(dy,dx);


let cp = {//control point for the bézier as a perpendicular line to thePath
  x:point.x + R*Math.cos(angle + Math.PI/2),
  y:point.y + R*Math.sin(angle + Math.PI/2)
}

//the new d attribute for the path
let d = `M${linePoints[0].x}, ${linePoints[0].y} Q${cp.x},${cp.y} ${linePoints[1].x}, ${linePoints[1].y}`;
//set the new d attribute
thePath.setAttributeNS(null,"d",d)
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 100vh;
}
path {
  stroke: black;
  fill: none;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox = "300 0 400 300">
<path id="thePath" d="M514, 222L488, 66" />
</svg>
```